# If $L=K(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_s)$, then each $\alpha_i$ is algebraic

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I do not understand the following remark from the lecture:

> Let $L/K$ be a finite field extension. If $L=K(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_s)$, then each $\alpha_i$ is algebraic.

Could you please explain this to me?

Comment: $L/K$ must be algebraic (or  finite) otherwise it is not true

Comment: @reuns: Sorry, I made an edit.

Comment: $L$ is a $n$-dimensional vector $K$-vector space implies that there are some $c_l\in K$ not all zero and such that $ \sum_{l=0}^n c_l \alpha_j^l =0$

Comment: For each $\alpha_i\in L$, since $L$ is finite-dimensional as a $K$-vector space, the elements $1,\alpha_i,\alpha_i^2,\dots\in L$ are $K$-linearly independent. This exactly says $\alpha_i$ is algebraic over $K$.

Comment: @reuns,@Kenta S: I am sorry, but I still do not quite get it; why can we assume that $1,\alpha_i,\alpha_i^2,\ldots,\alpha_i^n$ are linearly independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a well known theorem which says that every finite field extension is algebraic. Since $L/K$ is algebraic and $\alpha_i \in L$, they are algebraic over $K$.